# Javascript module, How to add extra content in develop build?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module

I want my development build to include some extra content. How can i use if statement inside an entry?

Example *(Not working)*:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'index.html': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.pug'),
    'search.html': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/search.pug'),
    !production && {'secret.html': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/secret.pug')}
  }
}
```

Comment: How should this work? I think it can be done there, without additional parsing, but please, explain us what would you like to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would pull out your `entry` object and build it based on your needs.

```
var entryPoints = {
    'index.html': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.pug'),
    'search.html': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/search.pug')
  }

if(!production) {
    Object.assign(entryPoints, {'secret.html': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/secret.pug')})
}
```

Your Webpack config would then now look like:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: entryPoints,
  //...
}
```

Comment: Nice, I could live with that. Worked perfectly!

Thank you!